ggplot2 boxplot not showing correct medians
I don't know why, but when I compute the median separate from the boxplot, is shows different medians than the boxplot shows.
my data:
structure(list(Value = c(16.2267911457943, NA, NA, -60.9768336023295, 
45.7713622254149, 6.02986395757871, -50.6449025302184, 83.6501594046511, 
287.317522877395, -18.0042302899501, 15.0727141880864, 20.9792501817316, 
-26.021952483978, -12.0308461005888, -15.2606684038631, 71.5445656251654, 
NA, 34.8221591601696, -53.7404017791857, -1.63398982908756, 278.185405728152, 
-4.96835320131497, -58.7120784356323, 370.271467415398, 0.146491986659995, 
-48.8688401313632, 10.8667221692923, 76.9409078494773, NA, NA, 
131.223330512424, -52.9893478627712, NA, -7.83526764335037, -37.0291601119597, 
118.240755380804, 55.6768951135366, 23.1321207464996, -15.3706271962233, 
NA, 152.08024610527, -42.055400068629, 127.368744732297, -26.9320875692473, 
133.719503762041, NA, 257.715418818484, 109.711048946109, 36.5675483370295, 
-51.9808690466175, -0.802880958999974, NA, 14.9320569765064, 
27.8925704890889, -28.3878192679801, NA, -16.4075599212064, -48.9374236167034, 
104.141100375876, NA, -14.9493906587284, 37.0649240161769, -18.8508687039991, 
-65.602043934446, 137.907889808966, -6.5220814328843, -71.203745994704, 
-48.2808956747233, 124.26832732689, -23.7004662334065, 262.921041185857, 
NA, -9.96577544213014, NA, 64.815871180774, NA, 15.6679387512368, 
-59.7583242151523, NA, NA, NA, -27.124629168775, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -18.382419583301, -36.143376135097, 57.6218476505755, -76.1447016989874, 
NA, -42.4039970179026, NA, 15.9333711177824, 7.40239340575722, 
-11.3600599753323, -29.947424954369, -0.680863552338243, 9.10587668870162, 
74.8235991357177, 88.6710936588603, -82.3176116790249, -10.4313457642559, 
-15.8692400736849, NA, 499.759265784965, 252.9242919009, -2.04098404515329, 
35.8950537382626, NA, -0.421421087565181, 11.9489608922443, NA, 
NA, 22.8027649553988, NA, 37.9693745379702, -24.7637821892334, 
NA, -11.2673746106332, -31.5089799080379, -80.3391883406062, 
-29.9983038274799, 54.6283009474221, -61.6135934766076, -48.5401703568297, 
NA, NA, -72.8679404121782, 16.1466131082535, -43.5232962655128, 
-0.811250552501514, NA, 168.018441562511, NA, NA, -26.8824299071516, 
56.8065618485559, -8.87536540873707, NA, 21.8263241241153, -50.5181327290331, 
NA, -20.2351176026656, NA, NA, -14.7598615369762, -57.0713769317939, 
-64.1771780436129, 133.473564344697, 37.3381887373264, -46.645744646877, 
85.0751094601544, NA, -60.3787658267308, -60.4156431852407, -11.3963662258402, 
-45.565899758334, -44.1578603141314, -66.4525896049789, -50.5174704624243, 
-1.83498479492783, -46.3346228838941, -6.64556720520367, 58.0483727201174, 
39.3127921396065, -41.3340840705311, 182.855331383154, 46.9617812836227, 
NA, 18.7673606183037, 165.931561063718, 22.929714881406, 233.108167469004, 
-6.16278194561769, NA, 34.1551962802122, -12.3306160081753, NA, 
49.6858229166201, 303.193371886174, 116.95948697053, NA, NA, 
49.5976113986749, 18.3502699821834, -4.04220340943788, 15.3497598206104, 
-69.6992709069366, 68.5816617241308, 76.6763413534583, 182.232448735482, 
-45.8785200274159, 88.7378672916263, -66.0470000372656, -16.1072699443716, 
31.1658582700767, NA, 14.1750411403289, -38.5875623729935, -31.7070226037086, 
-22.1653209279798, -29.4787742840903, NA, 14.6527086317266, -5.65034187987612, 
-38.6128998446212, NA, 116.661717110313, -55.6886976153585, 306.651372640632, 
NA, 5.2443642266029, NA, 164.251406927756, 8.08479755419994, 
-18.6080254820152, 4.65099387533456, NA, -72.7744256028191, NA, 
NA, -3.13475074117511, -53.7557081405056, 70.3554535337387, 263.11120615125, 
-38.3712332612174, NA, 44.7587133910893, 28.3872326442612, 55.5294816450682, 
NA, -2.85977990983236, 152.159242229752, 6.73616020826001, NA, 
NA, NA, 323.966046697711, -39.4294042444742, NA, -7.49744327501469, 
12.1950047233818, 153.383801169211, 100.117051893963, 42.7773110467366, 
NA, NA, 41.3100523510285, -24.2322401717261, NA, -14.8154417191547, 
50.6797004581804, -30.5276522747721, NA, 34.3499752464004, -15.7531435273882, 
-72.9840541195219, 181.883242158129, 40.501265092919, NA, -52.5763047325175, 
NA, 59.0423051291749, 13.3161809747956, 231.304936010334, 1.83627569545109, 
25.5198872962188, NA, NA, 38.0822620414481, 351.470791759223, 
66.6229327598367, -56.3660669654079, NA, -44.9189925669056, -41.8108725721503, 
6.6436567131886, 114.137319999401, -83.8694312828029, -18.0274335154422, 
29.5334952724214, -43.781278434763, -51.0804910811914, -6.76635825727331, 
NA, NA, 12.7128686742069, NA, 152.811424840734, NA, -28.1463847113787, 
114.871984917527, -10.4696843504697, NA, 91.9773888503264, 135.013394111388, 
69.5722573677824, NA, 220.987053705925, 8.15374866338603, 29.8045659714367, 
-29.1262638489299, NA, NA, -52.9431452912221, 132.941324461453, 
NA, -1.21570324985292, 325.923275123452, NA, NA, NA, 6.67178026394575, 
NA, -26.3587590713131, 152.743888743931, -44.0011631739789, 41.6558303178006, 
NA, NA, -45.5084935386024, NA, NA, 63.8096169521432, 38.856649609579, 
111.822418474399, -66.8281339138416, 33.2627448737628, -67.1282765038823, 
NA, -27.0329841382303, -3.50706073162479, -5.19355302237053, 
-28.4333116557054, 18.7230359573251, 36.889222123467, -54.1325384342192, 
34.5885739548095, 195.53649237022, NA, NA, 6.31279814290836, 
136.883323630556, -0.688474212344362, 0.581340032737085, 294.721454711977, 
-1.52263792221731, NA, -20.5332779484187, -38.8076876912657, 
NA, 38.8946368952969, 36.9653841705263, NA, 81.2287610054984, 
-67.9617536480286, -49.9524482029877, -29.8381147722512, 9.6083728417016, 
0.279253144996947, -22.7772759940713, -45.1824942323234, NA, 
NA, -51.6532105935927, 168.843706058664, -68.8408157633226, 289.469705334033, 
NA, -54.540997515853, -66.0134522318867, -49.3354964679914, -84.8690046984141, 
14.7571879523707, -61.6527045039384, -44.5278242315103, 35.3579306168703, 
6.96161857864835, -31.868145759608, NA, 45.7206221018007, -64.5962113283178, 
35.9909019722236, 3.25462544064177, 158.563580695974, -43.542017080742, 
69.3157093558246)), row.names = c(49L, 97L, 169L, 193L, 289L, 
313L, 361L, 385L, 1033L, 1297L, 1345L, 1417L, 1513L, 1585L, 1993L, 
2209L, 2401L, 2521L, 2545L, 2905L, 3169L, 3265L, 3961L, 3985L, 
4057L, 4633L, 4777L, 5089L, 5449L, 5473L, 5497L, 5545L, 5569L, 
5593L, 5617L, 5641L, 5665L, 5689L, 5737L, 5761L, 5809L, 5833L, 
5857L, 5881L, 5905L, 5929L, 5953L, 5977L, 6001L, 6049L, 6073L, 
6097L, 6121L, 6193L, 6217L, 6241L, 6289L, 6313L, 6361L, 6409L, 
6433L, 6457L, 6481L, 6529L, 6553L, 6577L, 6625L, 6649L, 6673L, 
6697L, 6721L, 6745L, 6793L, 6817L, 6841L, 6889L, 6913L, 6937L, 
6961L, 6985L, 7033L, 7057L, 7105L, 7129L, 7153L, 7201L, 7249L, 
7297L, 7321L, 7345L, 7441L, 7465L, 7513L, 7537L, 7561L, 7657L, 
7729L, 7753L, 7849L, 7897L, 7921L, 7969L, 7993L, 8065L, 8089L, 
8113L, 8161L, 8209L, 8233L, 8257L, 8497L, 8521L, 8545L, 8569L, 
8593L, 8617L, 8665L, 8833L, 9001L, 9025L, 9049L, 9097L, 9145L, 
9169L, 9217L, 9241L, 9265L, 9337L, 9385L, 9409L, 9457L, 9481L, 
9529L, 9553L, 9577L, 9601L, 9625L, 9745L, 9817L, 9841L, 9865L, 
9889L, 9913L, 9937L, 9961L, 10057L, 10081L, 10153L, 10177L, 10273L, 
10321L, 10417L, 10465L, 10489L, 10513L, 10609L, 10825L, 10969L, 
11017L, 11041L, 11065L, 11161L, 11233L, 11281L, 11329L, 11401L, 
11449L, 11497L, 11545L, 11593L, 11641L, 11761L, 11833L, 11857L, 
11905L, 11929L, 11953L, 11977L, 12049L, 12193L, 12241L, 12265L, 
12361L, 12385L, 12409L, 12553L, 12649L, 12673L, 12697L, 12721L, 
12745L, 12769L, 12817L, 12889L, 12913L, 12961L, 13009L, 13153L, 
13225L, 13249L, 13273L, 13297L, 13441L, 13489L, 13537L, 13561L, 
13609L, 13681L, 13705L, 13753L, 13777L, 13801L, 13825L, 13873L, 
13897L, 13921L, 13945L, 13969L, 14041L, 14257L, 14281L, 14305L, 
14329L, 14353L, 14377L, 14449L, 14497L, 14569L, 14593L, 14689L, 
14761L, 14785L, 14809L, 14833L, 14857L, 14905L, 14953L, 15025L, 
15049L, 15121L, 15145L, 15241L, 15265L, 15433L, 15505L, 15553L, 
15601L, 15649L, 15673L, 15697L, 15913L, 15937L, 15985L, 16009L, 
16033L, 16057L, 16081L, 16129L, 16153L, 16177L, 16201L, 16249L, 
16321L, 16345L, 16369L, 16417L, 16513L, 16561L, 16609L, 16681L, 
16705L, 16729L, 16753L, 16777L, 16849L, 16873L, 16897L, 16945L, 
16969L, 16993L, 17041L, 17065L, 17161L, 17209L, 17233L, 17257L, 
17281L, 17329L, 17353L, 17401L, 17425L, 17593L, 17761L, 17905L, 
17929L, 18025L, 18097L, 18217L, 18265L, 18289L, 18385L, 18505L, 
18601L, 18697L, 18745L, 18865L, 18889L, 18913L, 18937L, 18961L, 
19105L, 19129L, 19273L, 19513L, 19585L, 19633L, 19681L, 19705L, 
19825L, 19873L, 19897L, 19921L, 19945L, 20089L, 20137L, 20209L, 
20281L, 20305L, 20329L, 20497L, 20521L, 20545L, 20569L, 20617L, 
20713L, 20761L, 20785L, 20857L, 21193L, 21217L, 21241L, 21289L, 
21313L, 21481L, 21577L, 21601L, 21745L, 21817L, 21841L, 21865L, 
22105L, 22129L, 22201L, 22225L, 22321L, 22369L, 22417L, 22441L, 
22465L, 22489L, 22609L, 22633L, 22657L, 22801L, 22897L, 22921L, 
22969L, 23089L, 23617L, 23641L, 23713L, 23785L, 24313L, 24505L, 
24601L, 24649L, 24673L, 24865L, 24889L, 25129L, 25225L, 25297L, 
25345L, 25369L, 25417L, 25513L, 25585L, 25609L), class = "data.frame")

When I calculate the median, it comes out at 1.209 (ignoring missing). However, in the boxplot, it is showing a median below 0. I don't know where this discrepancy is coming from.
my boxplot:
box_plot <- sample %>%
  ggplot(aes( y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Time Point", 
       y = "Sphingolipid Percent Change", 
       title = "Sphingolipid Percent Change Medians Compared to Baseline") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") + # Adding horizontal line at y = 0
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, 2), labels = c("2 Years", "12 Years")) +
  ylim(-100, 100) + # Set y-limit for each facet
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "black", size = 6.5),
        strip.text = element_text(size = 8),
        strip.background = element_rect(fill='beige'),  
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white',color='black'),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', color = 'white'),
        panel.border =element_rect(colour='black', fill=NA),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))


From the docs (type ?ggplot2::ylim in the console): "This is a shortcut for supplying the limits argument to the individual scales. By default, any values outside the limits specified are replaced with NA.". You're removing some of your points from the calculations by doing this.

Replace ylim() with coord_caretesian() and you should see a different picture.
From the help page: "Setting limits on the coordinate system will zoom the plot (like you're looking at it with a magnifying glass), and will not change the underlying data like setting limits on a scale will."
sample |>
  ggplot(aes( y = Value)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ...
  #ylim(-100, 100) + # Set y-limit for each facet
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-100, 100)) +
  ...


See this post for more details.
